# Plotting of bounding box of tensorflow lite in kotlin not aligned to the object

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow, android-jetpack-compose, tensorflow-lite

I'm creating an app with object detection and capturing image. I followed https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/tutorials/object_detection and https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android for the sample code.

```
class PlotBoundingBox(
    context: Context,
    private val detectedObject: List<Detection>,
    private val imageHeight: Int,
    private val imageWidth: Int
) : View(context) {

    private var boundaryPaint = Paint()
    var scaleFactor = 1f

    init {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        boundaryPaint.color = Red.hashCode()
        boundaryPaint.strokeWidth = 5f
        boundaryPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        
        scaleFactor = max(width * 1f / imageWidth, height * 1f / imageHeight)

        for (result in detectedObject) {
            val boundingBox = result.boundingBox

            val top = boundingBox.top * scaleFactor
            val bottom = boundingBox.bottom * scaleFactor
            val left = boundingBox.left * scaleFactor
            val right = boundingBox.right * scaleFactor

            // Draw bounding box around detected objects
            val drawableRect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)

            canvas.drawRect(drawableRect, boundaryPaint)
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to plot the bounding box properly, but when i capture the image, the image is not the same as the display in Preview view(the captured image is adjusted to left compared to the display in Preview view). So I decided to set the scale to FILL_CENTER, but the bounding box is not plotting properly unlike using FILL_START. Below is my reference for the code of my implementation. My reference for the plotting of bounding box is here https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/objectdetection/OverlayView.kt.